# R can not be resolved as a variable error when creating a new android project

Tags: android, android-activity

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

`R.layout.activity_main` and `R.menu.main` are giving the error and i have no clue why .can anyone guide me to fix this error please

Comment: Clean your project then run.

Comment: what do you mean by clean your project ??

Comment: Go to Project -> Clean

Comment: cleaning the project didn't do anything

Comment: Hi bud, make sure that you've imported the right R ;) you probaby imported the Android one instead of yours ;)

Comment: i didn't imported anything i just create a new android project and this error occurred